# codeigniter url encrypt not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'daily_report/index/'.$this->encrypt->encode($this->session->userdata('employee_id')) ?>">
```

i have encrypted the above url using the codeigniter encrypt
i set the encryption key in codeigniter config file

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'gIoueTFDwGzbL2Bje9Bx5B0rlsD0gKDV';
```

and i called in the autoload

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','form_validation','encrypt','encryption','database');
```

when the ulr(href) load into the url it look like this

```
http://localhost/hrms/daily_report/index/FVjGcz4qQztqAk0jaomJiAFBZ/vKVSBug1iGPQeKQCZ/K7+WUE4E/M9u1EjWh3uKTKeIhExjGKK1dJ2awL0+zQ==
```

but the url is not decoded, and i;m not getting the employee_id it shows empty.

```
public function index($employee_id) {
        $save_employee_id = $employee_id;
        // decoding the encrypted employee id
        $get_employee_id = $this->encrypt->decode($save_employee_id);
        echo $employee_id; // answer: FVjGcz4qQztqAk0jaomJiAFBZ
        echo "<br>";
        echo $get_employee_id; // is display the null
        echo "<br>";

        exit();
        // get the employee daily report
        $data['get_ind_report'] =           $this->daily_report_model->get_ind_report($get_employee_id);
        // daily report page
        $data['header'] = "Daily Report";
        $data['sub_header'] = "All";
        $data['main_content'] = "daily_report/list";
        $this->load->view('employeelayout/main',$data);
    }
```

complete url(3) is

```
FVjGcz4qQztqAk0jaomJiAFBZ/vKVSBug1iGPQeKQCZ/K7+WUE4E/M9u1EjWh3uKTKeIhExjGKK1dJ2awL0+zQ==
```

it shows only

```
FVjGcz4qQztqAk0jaomJiAFBZ
```

i tried to change in the

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-zA-Z 0-9~%.:_\-@=+';
```

by / in the permitted uri chars
but it throwing error
So,  i need to encryption the $id in the url using the codeigniter encrypt class and decrypt in the server side to get the actual $id, So that i fetch data from the DB. any help would be appreciated

Comment: You might want to read this post on [URL parameter encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php); especially if you're using the old CI_Encrypt class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend encryption class and avoid the `/` to get it working. Place this class in your `application/libraries` folder. and name it as `MY_Encrypt.php`.

```
class MY_Encrypt extends CI_Encrypt
{
    /**
     * Encodes a string.
     * 
     * @param string $string The string to encrypt.
     * @param string $key[optional] The key to encrypt with.
     * @param bool $url_safe[optional] Specifies whether or not the
     *                returned string should be url-safe.
     * @return string
     */
    function encode($string, $key="", $url_safe=TRUE)
    {
        $ret = parent::encode($string, $key);

        if ($url_safe)
        {
            $ret = strtr(
                    $ret,
                    array(
                        '+' => '.',
                        '=' => '-',
                        '/' => '~'
                    )
                );
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    /**
     * Decodes the given string.
     * 
     * @access public
     * @param string $string The encrypted string to decrypt.
     * @param string $key[optional] The key to use for decryption.
     * @return string
     */
    function decode($string, $key="")
    {
        $string = strtr(
                $string,
                array(
                    '.' => '+',
                    '-' => '=',
                    '~' => '/'
                )
        );

        return parent::decode($string, $key);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is great, can you help me how to use this in controller and in the href. please.........

Comment: you don't have to do anything just place the file and it will work

Comment: thank for your help, i appreciate the time for my question and got, it is working well

Answer (score 1):

```
FVjGcz4qQztqAk0jaomJiAFBZ/vKVSBug1iGPQeKQCZ/K7+WUE4E/M9u1EjWh3uKTKeIhExjGKK1dJ2awL0+zQ==
```

Shows

```
FVjGcz4qQztqAk0jaomJiAFBZ
```

If you look at your url closely, you could see that after the result which has been shown there is a '/' . Now any string after that will be treated as another segment. Hence it could not decode.
The encrypt library in this case would not work.

Either you stop passing that through the URL or use another different technique base_encode().

Hope that helps

Comment: *"stop passing that through the URL"* - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as the character "/" is part of html uri delimiter. Instead you can work around it by avoiding that character in html url by rawurlencoding your encrytion output string before attaching it to url.

\edit:

I tried rawurlencode, but wasn't able to get the proper output.

Finally succeeded by using this code.
Define two functions:

```
function hex2str( $hex ) {
  return pack('H*', $hex);
}

function str2hex( $str ) {
  return array_shift( unpack('H*', $str) );
}
```

Then use call str2hex and pass it the encrypted user id to convert encrypted string into hexcode.
Reverse the process to get the correct string so that you can decrypt it.

I was able to properly encode and decode:

```
"FVjGcz4qQztqAk0jaomJiAFBZ/vKVSBug1iGPQeKQCZ/K7+WUE4E/M9u1EjWh3uKTKeIhExjGKK1dJ2awL0+zQ=="
```

to:

```
"46566a47637a3471517a7471416b306a616f6d4a694146425a2f764b56534275673169475051654b51435a2f4b372b57554534452f4d397531456a576833754b544b65496845786a474b4b31644a3261774c302b7a513d3d"
```

The url would become rather long though.

Comment: thanks for your help, you can do it in better way, create a helper file in helper folder and copy the code from the above @karman into the helper file, and use it wherever you want. that's it, You can also write your own helper class.....

Comment: Yes, his solution is definitely elegant!